# Minecraft server command for Discord: "OSError: Server did not respond with any information!"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, runtime-error, minecraft

So I'm trying to make a discord command that returns the latency and player numbers using "discord.py" and "mcstatus". Every time I run the command I get the error "**OSError: Server did not respond with any information!**" I've tried using `MinecraftServer.lookup("mc.hypixel.net")`, `MinecraftServer.lookup("mc.hypixel.net:25565")`, `MinecraftServer("mc.hypixel.net", 25565)`, and some with other servers, but they all respond with the same error.

Here's my code:

```
import discord
import mcstatus
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='\\')
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="for \\\'s")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)

@client.command()
async def mcserver(ctx):
    server = MinecraftServer.lookup("mc.hypixel.net")
    status = server.status()
    latency = server.ping()
    print("The server replied in {0} ms".format(latency))
    await ctx.channel.send("The server has {0} players and replied in {1}
ms".format(status.players.online, status.latency))
```

Comment: Does the status and ping work?

Comment: also try to check if enable-query is set to true

Comment: please check your version of mcstatus and python as well

Comment: Status and ping does not work. Python is version 3.9.6, and I believe Mcstatus is up to date, as I just downloaded it today. Also, how would I check if enable-query is set to true?

Comment: @seraph `enable-query` is a server-side setting to allow querying of the server for more information, like a full player-list. OP however isn't querying the server, but only pinging it and getting the status. These methods should be supporty by any MC server version >= 1.7 .

Comment: Since .query() is not being used there's no reason to worry about `enable-query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `server.ping()` function. Tbh, I don't know why its not working, but it isn't working for me either. But happily, the latency is included in the `server.status()` call.

---

```py
import discord
import mcstatus
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='\\')
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="for \\\'s")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)

@client.command()
async def mcserver(ctx):
    server = MinecraftServer.lookup("mc.hypixel.net")
    status = server.status()
    print("The server replied in {0} ms".format(status.latency))
    await ctx.channel.send("The server has {0} players and replied in {1}
ms".format(status.players.online, status.latency))
```

---

I tested this code on my machine, and it works flawlessly.
Maybe make an issue on [the github project of mcstats](https://github.com/Dinnerbone/mcstatus) explaining the issue.

Comment: wait. the ping function fails the whole program?

Comment: Seems to be the case, yes